# Practical use of the friendly_name field in Bigquery views/tables

Tags: google-bigquery

Several [documentation examples](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#examples) mention that you can customize `friendly_name`
this is different from the name of the table.

> Example: friendly_name="my_table". This property is equivalent to the
>   friendlyName table resource property

I am wondering what is the practical use to have a different `table name`, and a different `friendly name`? Does the UI or console display something different when these are used?

Answer (score 2):

In Classic UI when you set friendly name - you get an extra field in Table Info called "Name" with value of whatever you set as Friendly Name - like for example "My Favorite Table"

[image]

In New UI same value can be found in second row of Table Info and is called - surprisingly - "Friendly name"

[image]

Rather than this I don't see any use of it so far in both UIs

Comment: Can we use Friendly Name while querying ? What all benefits one can get using Friendly Names ? Why Friendly Name when we have description already ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the friendly_name to query a table.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).